# how to delete a record and go to delete page in rails 7 after installing ujs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-7, rails-ujs

I am using Rails 7 and also install ujs but whenever i click on delete button Get request call rather than destroy request and i go to view record page rather then delete employee page. This is the code of delete link:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", employee_path(employee), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", data: { confirm: "Are You sure to delete this employee" } %>
```

and this is the code of delete action from controller file:

```
def destroy
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    if @employee.destroy
      redirect_to employees_path, notice: "Employee has been deleted"
    end
  end
```

Comment: How did you add rails-ujs? How do your `config/importmap.rb` and `app/javascript/application.js` files look like?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma this is the code of application.js: import Rails from "@rails/ujs";
Rails.start();
and below is the code of impotmap.rb file : # Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"

Comment: is "@rails/ujs" pinned in the importmap.rb file?

Comment: No. how to do so, kindly let me know the remaining instructions @SebastiánPalma

Comment: Try adding this line at the end in your importmap.rb file;

`pin "@rails/ujs", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@rails/ujs@7.0.6/lib/assets/compiled/rails-ujs.js"`

Comment: Then reload the server and try again, let's see if it changes anything.

Comment: Thank you the problem is solved now. Thank you, furthermore can you please let me know what was the problem ? @SebastiánPalma

Comment: Exactly that, the JS module for rails-ujs wasn't imported into your app.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma i have add this in my importmap.rb file but it still do not deleting the record and go to show page. please check https://i.stack.imgur.com/mODXl.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, you've partially installed rails-ujs, but you're still missing the import of the rails-ujs JS module.

You could try *pinning* the @rails/ujs module into your `config/importmap.rb` file and restarting the server:

```
# config/importmap.rb
pin "@rails/ujs", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@rails/ujs@7.0.6/lib/assets/compiled/rails-ujs.js"
```

See [`rails/importmap-rails`](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails) for further info on `pin`.